# WordPress: How do I hide a certain menu item for a custom user role?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am looking to have some CSS trigger based on whether a WordPress user has a certain user role assigned.

I've linked below the code I thought would allow certain CSS to trigger based on a user role.

```
function wpmu_role_based_style() {
    if ( current_user_can( 'wholesale_customer' ) ) { ?>
    
        <style>
            .wholesale-shop {display:none;}
        </style>
    <?php  } ?>
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding that? You need to use hooks like `add_action()` for your purpose.

Comment: It's in the functions.php folder. I added a test class;
'''
 .test {display: block!important;}
 img {display: none;}
'''
and 
'''
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpmu_role_based_style', 99 );
'''
To see if I could hide a test element, but no luck. Apologies for my formatting - new here.

Answer (score 1):

You can add body classes for different user roles by using `body_class` filter. For example,

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'body_class_user_role' );

function body_class_user_role( $classes ) {

    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        $user_role = wp_get_current_user()->roles;
        $classes[] = 'user-role-' . $user_role[0];

    } 
    return $classes;
}
```

Then use the class like below example:

```
.logged-in.user-role-wholesale_customer .wholesale-shop { 
    display: none; 
}
```

You can add the CSS to the custom theme or the "[Additional CSS](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/)" section of Customizer.